# I have a public folder in my Node.js/Express.js project which contains some images. When I try to access those images through URL, I get 404 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a Node.js/Express js project with the following folder structure

```
root
----bin
----controllers
----middleware
----models
----node_modules
----public
--------images
------------test.png
----routes
----views
```

I'm trying to figure out what URL I need to access in order to be served the test.png image that is inside the `public/images` folder. I thought it would be the following url:

```
http://localhost:3000/public/images/test.png
```

However, I get a `"Not Found, 404"` error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register an API middleware to serve the static files from the disk.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('path/to/static/directory'))
```

in your case, you can use,

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Refer https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html for additional details.

Comment: use absolute path `var path = require('path');` and `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`